# What does parent and view mean in onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)

Tags: java, android

I have multiple spinners on my activities and want to pass the value of the specific spinner to other activity using
this code

```
@Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if (view == A1_3G) {
            if (position == 1) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Male", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if (position == 2) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }


    }
```

I can't seem to understand it
I also referred to
 https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener
Thanks for your help

Comment: I already got the answer from a senior thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

welcome to our community .

Parent means the Object that you use it for creating items like RecycelerView and ListView and so .
u can get all properties of it.

View means layout of your single item that can u call it with view.textView

Hope it was helpful.

Have good Coding ;)